# NoClassDefFoundError: /org/Hibernate/SessionFactory while executing maven .war

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, war

I'm having trouble creating an executable war for my program using maven.

The current issue is that when I run the program inside Eclipse, everything works fine, however once the .war is built it doesn't work - it throws a NoClassDefFoundError: /org/Hibernate/SessionFactory.

Since that is the first class called by the main method I suspect it's not a problem with hibernate but rather with the war's classpath, but I don't understand why. This is my pom.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
   Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
   contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
   this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
   The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
   (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
   the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   limitations under the License.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>pipe</groupId>
 <artifactId>pipe</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>1.0</version>
  <!-- TODO project name  -->
 <name>pipe</name>
 <description></description>
 
 <!--
  <organization>
   <name>company name</name>
   <url>company url</url>
  </organization>
 -->
 <licenses>
  <license>
   <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
   <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
   <distribution>repo</distribution>
  </license>
 </licenses>
 <properties>
  <wicket.version>7.4.0</wicket.version>
  <jetty9.version>9.2.13.v20150730</jetty9.version>
  <log4j.version>2.5</log4j.version>
  <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <!-- allowed values: R7, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0 or none -->
  <wtp.version>none</wtp.version>
 </properties>
 <dependencies>
  <!--  WICKET DEPENDENCIES -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
   <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
   <version>${wicket.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <!-- OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
   <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
   <version>${wicket.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicketstuff-editable-grid</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicketstuff-inmethod-grid</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.wicket/wicket-datetime -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-datetime</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.0</version>
</dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.wicket/wicket-auth-roles -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-auth-roles</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.0</version>
</dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wicketstuff/wicketstuff-minis -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicketstuff-minis</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
    <artifactId>izpack-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>inmethod-grid</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.14</version>
</dependency>

  <!-- LOGGING DEPENDENCIES - LOG4J -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
   <version>${log4j.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
   <version>${log4j.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  

  <!--  JUNIT DEPENDENCY FOR TESTING -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>${junit.version}</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <!--  JETTY DEPENDENCIES FOR TESTING  -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
   <artifactId>jetty-all</artifactId>
   <version>${jetty9.version}</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <build>
  <resources>
   <resource>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
   </resource>
   <resource>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
    <includes>
     <include>**</include>
    </includes>
    <excludes>
     <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
   </resource>
  </resources>
  <testResources>
   <testResource>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
   </testResource>
   <testResource>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <directory>src/test/java</directory>
    <includes>
     <include>**</include>
    </includes>
    <excludes>
     <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
   </testResource>
  </testResources>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.7</source>
     <target>1.7</target>
     <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
     <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
     <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty9.version}</version>
    <configuration>
     <systemProperties>
      <systemProperty>
       <name>maven.project.build.directory.test-classes</name>
       <value>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</value>
      </systemProperty>
     </systemProperties>
     <jettyXml>${project.basedir}/src/test/jetty/jetty.xml,${project.basedir}/src/test/jetty/jetty-ssl.xml,${project.basedir}/src/test/jetty/jetty-http.xml,${project.basedir}/src/test/jetty/jetty-https.xml</jettyXml>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
     <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
     <wtpversion>${wtp.version}</wtpversion>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
     <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
     <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
     <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
     <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
      <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>main-class-placement</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <move todir="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/">
                                    <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/classes/">
                                        <include name="Main.class" />
                                    </fileset>
                                </move>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jetty-classpath</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeGroupIds>org.eclipse.jetty,javax.servlet</includeGroupIds>
                            <excludeArtifactIds>jsp-api,jstl</excludeArtifactIds>
                            <excludes>META-INF/ECLIPSEF.*</excludes>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

 <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>Apache Nexus</id>
   <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
   <releases>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
   </releases>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </repository>
 </repositories>
 </project>
```

All dependencies are also in the build classpath in Eclipse.
I'm trying to run it with the command java -jar pipe-1.0.war by the way.

Any help is appreciated

-edit-

exact error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/SessionFactory
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.SessionFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 0):

if you decompile the jar and check the Manifest file you will probably see that the class with the main method is not declared properly.

So you can try adding this plugin to your pom xml file:

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>yourpackage.Mainclass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the main class definition is correct - it's under "default package" and it's called Main. It is found when running.

Answer (score -1):

Hibernate 5.2 and later versions require at least Java 1.8, whereas you're using 1.7 at:

```
<configuration>
    <source>1.7</source>
    <target>1.7</target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I changed that but I still get the same problem :(